# Can't call native lock screen after custom lock screen

Tags: java, android

I'm changing a lock screen using `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

It change native lock sreen to custom perfectly, but I can't change to native again. How can I do it? Should I somehow disable `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver`?

code within `Service`

```
if(isMustBeLocked) {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    mReceiver = new LockScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    super.onCreate();
}
```

code within `code within BroadcastReciever`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        if(!LockScreenService.isMustBeLocked) {
            // need to do something here
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Intent intent11 = new Intent(context,LockScreenActivity.class);
        intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
    }
}
```